# Simple call to method inside Browserified js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have this HTML file

> ```
> <body>
>     <div id="demodiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
>     <script src="chart.js"></script>
>     <script>
>         draw_chart();
>     </script>
> </body> </html>
> ```

### Chart.js file (THIS WORKS!)

> function draw_chart() {
>
> ```
> var g = new Dygraph(
>         document.getElementById("demodiv"),
>         "chart.csv", // path to CSV file
>         {}          // options
>     );
>
> g.ready(function() {
>
> }); }
> ```

Then - i tried to install browerify, so i installed it and ran the cmd with

> "browserify chart.js -o bundle.js"

and of course i also changed the script src in the HTML file from

> chart.js to bundle.js

### But is just doesn't work --> Uncaught ReferenceError: draw_chart is not defined

> (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof
>   require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return
>   i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw
>   f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var
>   l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var
>   n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return
>   n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var
>   o=0;o
>
> function draw_chart() {
>
> ```
> g.ready(function() {
> ```
>
> ...custom code...
>       }); } },{}]},{},[1]);

Why can't the HTML page find the JS method draw_chart after i browerified it?

I guess i'm simply missing some thing really obvious!? Its the first time i'm using Browerify...

Answer (score 0):

I just realized - that Browerify don't work the way i expected...

Solution: I removed the call to the Draw_Chart from the HTML file and inserted the call in the bundle.js file instead... Thats all... :-)